# Duplicate or Copy repository in Bitbucket using REST API

Tags: java, git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I have a base repository in Bitbucket project and I need to create new repository based on this base repository using REST API. The new repository has to contain all the files from the base repository.

How can I do do it?

Answer (score -1):

The way to do it is by forking the repository this way:

- Using Http POST
- URI:
  http://{IP}:{PORT}/rest/api/1.0/projects/{PROJECT_NAME}/repos/{REPO_NAME}/
- Authorization - use BasicAuth
- Content-Type  - "application/json"
- Body:
  `{
  "slug": "URL_FRIENDLY_NAME",
  "name": "NEW_REPO_NAME",
  "project": {
      "key": "PROJECT_NAME"
  }
  }`